# Position of Gtk.Dialog

Tags: pygtk

is there a possiblity to change the position of a Gtk.Dialog?

At the moment it's poppin up right in the center of my main-Window. Can I set values, so it's more to the left or right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimal example of how you might want to move a Gtk.Dialog to your desired position:

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk


class DialogExample(Gtk.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent, x, y):
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, title="My Dialog", transient_for=parent, flags=0)

        self.set_default_size(150, 50)

        # Get current position of dialog
        pos = self.get_position()
        # Move dialog to the desired location
        self.move(pos[0] + x, pos[1] + y)

        label = Gtk.Label(label="This is a dialog to display additional information")

        box = self.get_content_area()
        box.add(label)
        self.show_all()


class DialogWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Dialog Example")

        self.set_border_width(6)

        button = Gtk.Button(label="Open dialog")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)

        self.add(button)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        # Open dialog 200 px to the left relative to main window
        dialog = DialogExample(self, -200, 0) 
        dialog.run()
        dialog.destroy()


win = DialogWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

**Sources:**

- https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/button_widgets.html
- [How to position an independent Window in an exact location on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876926/how-to-position-an-independent-window-in-an-exact-location-on-the-screen)

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't seeing the chance to give the '-200' for the parent.